# Creating directories in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-mars

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIvME.png)I'm very new to the Java world so please forgive my ignorance.

What is the optimal way to create 1000 New directories in Java?

knowing that I have a specific number for each new directory for example ( Create **D\NEW_Directories\DIR101234...DIR107601...DIR108234... to DIR#1000**.

I already have the specific 1000 numbers list that I want to plug in in a code to create the new 100 empty directories for them. I found a couple of examples on how to create a single directory but not multiple ones. I'm using Eclipse Marse 2 in a Win64 environment.

Comment: you can use `java.io.File#mkdirs`.

Answer (score 0):

In my example i use "i" like suffix , and i check if direcory exists.

The solution doesn't depend of the IDE you are using , everything used in here
it is included in the java standard libraries.

```
String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "pathwhereyouwantcreatefolders";
        for(int i = 1 ;i<5;i++){
            File folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER+"_"+i);
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            }//for
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have anderstood good your question, here is the code example (just change 10 with 1000).

```
import java.io.File;

public class Directories {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //We are creating 10 directories in a parent directory called NEW_DIRECTORIES
        boolean new_dir = new File("NEW_DIRECTORIES").mkdir();
        boolean successCreation;
        if (new_dir) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                do {
                    int folderName = (int) (Math.random() * 899999) + 100000; //Give a random number from 100000 to 999999
                    String aDirName = "NEW_DIRECTORIES/" + folderName;
                    successCreation = new File(aDirName).mkdir();
                } while (!successCreation); //We need this condition to make sure that a number has not been chosen twice
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output should be like this (**TESTED**).

[image]

Comment: So I have a list of 1000 random 5 digits numbers that are not in sequence and I want the new directories to be named as those numbers without the 'DIR' so they will look like the picture I just attached to the question.

Comment: So you need to make some changes, like using random() of the math library. I updated the answer

Comment: U welcome, is that the right answer? You should learn a bit about random function and mkdir

Comment: do you have actually the folders names? Where are they so you could automate getting them (programmatically)?

Comment: Yes, I have them in an Excel sheet. I was thinking of copying them and past them like new (folderName =String[]{"105330","112233",.....etc} )

Comment: Using jexcelapi  you can fetch the xls file and get your names programmatically. I worked before with it. If you want, update your question and put an image of the xls file (you will need the columns order in the sheet of the file)